# Powershell determine if a TIFF file is a Multi-TIFF

Tags: image, powershell, tiff

I'd like to know if it's possible to determine using Powershell if a TIFF file has several pages.

And if so, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: : ), sorry, but how can I do that?

Comment: [list](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/TIFF).

Answer (score 3):

whit something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$a = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile( "C:\PS\multipage_tif_example.tif" )

if ($a.GetFrameCount( [System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension]::Page ) -gt 1 )
{ "Tiff is multi pages" }
else
{ "Tiff is single page" }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Using this I was able to produce a report of how many pages each of my tif files in a number of directories had. [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")\n  $Tab = [char]9\n $ReportFile = "report.txt"\n Write-Output "FileName $Tab Page Count" > $ReportFile\n Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.tif | ForEach-Object {\n  $Count = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile( $_ ).GetFrameCount( [System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension]::Page)\n  Write-Output "$_.FullName %Tab $Count"\n  } >> $ReportFile

Comment: The .FullName in the Write-Output isn't exactly right. But it got the job done and I just had to do a find/replace on the report to remove it.